# How to Crack A RAR Password without any tool

Tags: passwords, rar

I have a .rar file with unknown password.. Please specify the process to unlock it without any tool if there is any.

Comment: If the process is same for .zip files, please mention...

Comment: It wouldn't be a very good lock if you didn't need a key or any tools to unlock it . . .

Answer (score 5):

### Manual brute force

Assuming time isn't a constraint:

1. Buy yourself a slab of beer
2. Sit yourself down at your computer
3. Start guessing

Comment: Isn't a computer a tool...?